# QuickBooks Desktop 2017 Pro crash on Windows 10 64 bit after opening company files and logged in

Tags: windows-10, crash, quickbooks

I have a Quickbooks desktop 2017 pro which have been working fine on my laptop with windows 10 64 bits. However, since a couple of years ago, When I open a company file, it allows login, and then shows the initial notices, etc., then, it seems to try to display some web page, a blank page body and with a long web address with omission due to the popup browser width not wide enough to display. then, the Quickbooks display shall crash! The QuickBooks window shall disappear without a trace!

I have tried a number of ways, from reinstall the QuickBooks Desktop software, to install some tools from Quickbooks support website, like QuickBooks Tool Hub, ran through serveral attempts, but none of them succeeded. I have tried to open the Sample Company from QuickBooks, it crashes as well! The Windows 10 should be uptodate with automatic installation! Please help!!!

Here is the hardware/software info:

```
Lenovo Yoga C740-14IML
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10710U CPU @ 1.10GHz
1.61 GHz RAM
16.0 GB (15.8 GB Available)
Windows 10 Pro Version 22H2
Date of installation    ‎5/‎7/‎2021
OS internal version 19045.3208
```

Comment: Make sure the QuickBooks monitor service is running.  QBCFMonitorService. Otherwise try reinstalling QuickBooks. Uninstall, restart, Install.

Comment: This problem is specific to company files. Perhaps you should update your Quickbooks version, or ask for support from your company.